# Genderless referral to a person as existent in Thai language

Tags: pronouns, gender, thai, titles

While learning Thai I came across something I never knew from other languages:

The titles *Khun* (คุณ) and *Than* (ท่าน) while *Than* is said in down tone (`'`):

- Thai people would most often refer nonformally to a foreign (Thai or not) with `Khun first_name`
- Thai people would most often refer formally to a venerated official (usually a government official) with `Than first_name`
- It is generally avoided to name a person by his alleged last name
- These titles are generally omitted if the referred person is a close fried or family member.

It is important for me to emphasize that both *Khun* and *Than* have nothing to do with gender sensation or gender identity.

Does *genderless referral to a person as existent in Thai language* existent in other langues as well and if so, in which?

Comment: I think of these particles more like titles. "Your majesty", "your highness" comes to mind.

Comment: @Patrick wouldn't the analogy be with *his/her majesty* or *his/her highness* though? If so we are back to gendered references. *Reverend* or *Dr* or *professor* maybe. There's also *Mx* but I'm not sure that counts because it was invented precisely because the English language did not have a genderless form of address that wasn't specific to some occupation or social status.

Comment: “Majesty”, “excellence”, “comrade”. In most languages I know these are used irrespectively of gender. Do they qualify? At least “comrade” is often used with a surname, is it essential for you?

Comment: Japanese *-san*. It's a fair point that *his majesty* etc. are only gendered in English because of the way that possessives work in English.

Comment: East Asian languages have a lot of these. BTW, Thai คุณ is cognate to Japanese 君 (*kun*), but 君 is not genderless (being reserved for males).

Comment: German *Beamte*, "ombudsman", though later feminized adding *-in*.

Comment: I think it might be worth clarifying your question a bit. I think you are looking for a mode of address that can be used for people generally, regardless of gender, but you are getting suggestions that can only be used for people holding specific positions. I know *than* exists in Lao and would assume it is genderless. I don't think there is an equivalent in Vietnamese. Then there is Japanese *san*. FWIW I'm not convinced that the existence of this type of mode of address really tells you much about a language / culture. It's not as though Thai or Japanese don't also have modes of address...

Comment: ... that do specify gender, so I don't think it could be argued e.g. that gender has historically been perceived as less important in those speech communities than it has in others. I would link it more to the habit of describing things by general category + specific description, IOW khun [name of person] is much like ma [fruit] or phak [vegetable]. Speakers of Western languages don't feel the need to do this  - they just say the name of the fruit by itself. the SE Asian approach is bound to lead to a wider range of category prefixes/suffixes than you would find in English or German.

Comment: Well, bounty expires in one day --- if anyone can synthesize an answer, please have this bounty, otherwise it will fade away...